# spark mssql connector - java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver

Tags: sql-server, azure, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm getting the below Error when I try to connect to Azure SQL database using Spark connector MSSQL.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o34.load.
: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:315)
```

List of python packages in my project

```
adal==1.2.4

certifi==2022.5.18.1

cffi==1.15.0

charset-normalizer==2.0.12

cryptography==37.0.2

idna==3.3

py4j==0.10.9

pycparser==2.21

PyJWT==2.4.0

pyspark==3.1.3

python-dateutil==2.8.2

requests==2.27.1

six==1.16.0

urllib3==1.26.9
```

sparks-submit command that i used, it runs within a container and the path to jars provided is correct,

```
spark-submit --master local[2] --deploy-mode client --jars /workspaces/dev_con3/jars/spark-mssql-connector_2.12-1.2.0.jar,/workspaces/dev_con3/jars/adal4j-1.6.7.jar --verbose spark_mssql_connector.py
```

base image for container:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/vscode/devcontainers/python:0-3.10-bullseye

Laptop uses M1 pro chip.

application code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
.builder\
.appName('Test_AzSQL_Connection')\
.getOrCreate()

user_name = "some_user" 
password = "some_password"

table_name = "some_table"

SERVER_ADDR ="somename.database.windows.net"
server_name = "jdbc:sqlserver://{SERVER_ADDR}"
database_name = "some_db_name"
url = server_name + ";" + "databaseName=" + database_name + ";"

jdbc_df = spark.read \
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") \
    .option("url", url) \
    .option("dbtable", table_name) \
    .option("user", user_name) \
    .option("password", password) \
    .option("encrypt", "true") \
    .option("hostNameInCertificate", "*.database.windows.net") \
    .load() \
    .limit(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error mainly happens because of the package missing `mysql:mysql-connector-java`, please install this [**package.**](https://search.maven.org/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java)

If you are not downloaded the jar package. You can download the JAR from [**here**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/download-microsoft-jdbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017).

**Sample code:**

```
Servername = "jdbc:sqlserver://<AzureSQLserverName>.database.windows.net:1433"
dbname = "<dbname>"
url = Servername + ";" + "databaseName=" + dbname + ";"
user = "<userName>"
password = "<Password>"
dbtable = "<TableName>"
print("read data from SQL server table  ")
df = spark.read 
    .format("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.spark") 
    .option("url", url) 
    .option("dbtable", dbtable) 
    .option("user", user) 
    .option("password", password).load()
df.show(5)
```

For more in detail, please **refer** below links:

https://the.agilesql.club/2019/10/how-to-connect-spark-to-ms-sql-server-without-error-jvmbridge-java.sql.sqlexception-no-suitable-driver/

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-jdbc.html

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/573544/how-to-install-the-package-commicrosoftsqlserverjd.html